# Linear Topology using VMs

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internal

I am using virtual box to instantiate 3 Virtual Machines A,B,C. I want both A and C to be able to communicate with B. In simpler terms, I need a linear topology between A,B and C [ A<->B<->C ]

I am using "internal network" mode in network settings for each of the VM. I am able to ping both A and C using B however, when I execute tracepath to C on VM_A, it isn't able to reach instead of showing A, B, C as hops.

VM_B has 2 adapters, each of which is connected to internal network "neta" and "netc" respectively.

I cannot use mininet to do this. Anyone has done this kind of simulation using multiple VMs before?

Comment: And is your VM_B guest set up to act as an IP router ? (Depends on the operating system how you do that or whether you can do it at all)

Comment: VM_B is a linux (ubuntu) instance and set up as a router using echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Comment: Then VM_A needs a static route to the subnet of VM_C with VM_B as a gateway, and vice versa on VM_C. Unless VM_B is already the default gateway of VM_A and VM_C. Make sure there arn't any firewall rules on your VMs that prevent the communications you want. Make sure `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` reads back 1.

Comment: I have added a static route using this command however this doesn't seem to work around, 
sudo route add -net VM_C netmask 255.255.255.0 gw VM_B?
Any other specifications too?

Comment: No, that's probably it. You'll need to do the same on VM_C, route add -net VM_A netmask 255.255.255.0 gw VM_B. Then start debugging with tcpdump. See where the packets end up. Do they appear on adapter 1 on VM_B ? Do they appear on adapter 2 on VM_B ? Do they appear on VM_C ?

Comment: @KritiPandey All 3 machines will talk to your VM host network and not from A to B and then to C, hence traceroute is not showing this, If you are still ok you can configure host based IP deny access rule which will block this.

Comment: @nos: Tried tcpdump. even though the ARP request does appear on both adapters of VM_B and also appear on VM_C, the reply for tracepath is still "!H". Any other thing I could try?

Comment: Thanks. flushing the iptables firewall rules worked. :)